# Leap day removal

Tags: r, date, leap-year

My Dataset contains two columns, one with `Date` as YYYYMMDD and a column with another value.

The date column is type `Date`, as I used function `as.Date` to transform the values from `int` to `character` to `Date` `%Y%m%d`.

I am using daily data, therefore, I have to delete the leap days. I tried many things, but I did not find anything that works yet. I want to remove the 29th of February for each leap year (i.e. 1992, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016, 2020). How can I do this?

```
dsKNMI$Date <- as.character(dsKNMI$Date)
dsKNMI$Date <- as.Date(dsKNMI$Date, format = "%Y%m%d")
```

Dates are in format 1990-12-31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Base R`,

```
dsKNMI <- dsKNMI[!(format(dsKNMI$Date, format = "%m") =="02" &
                      format(dsKNMI$Date, format = "%d")=="29"),]
```